# Work with Autolayout programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

i try to achieve the following Design with UIView´s, it should be all done with Autolayout and no hard coded Frames:

[image]

I do it with an "for loop" like this:

```
CGFloat y_coordinate = 0;

for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
{

   UIView * testView =  [UIView new];

   testView.frame = CGRectMake(testView.frame.origin.x, y_coordinate, testView.frame.size.width, testView.frame.size.height);

    testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"testView":testView};

    testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.view addSubview:testView];

    //View should have the same Width and Height and a little Padding between them!
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:testView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         multiplier:0.5
                                                           constant:-4]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:testView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:testView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:-4]];

    if(i % 2) {

        //odd

        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[testView]-0-|"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:viewsDictionary]];

       //Here i need the Height of the View and not hard coded like here...but how?

           y_coordinate += 200;

    } else {

          //even

        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[testView]"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:viewsDictionary]];


    } 
}
```

My Problem is that i don´t know how to place the Views correctly under each other with Autolayout?

Comment: that's quite simple -> [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-(%.0f)-[testView]", y_coordinate] options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings( testView )]]

Comment: if you want to make it more "complicated" -> you can create constraints between your new view and upper view like this -> [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[upperView]-(%.0f)-[testView]", PADDING_CONSTANT] options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings( upperView ,testView )]]; where -> PADDING_CONSTANT is a constant gap between two views in vertical, upperView is a saved reference of last known upper view

Comment: Omg, that did the Trick, thank you very much!!! I will accept your answer if you declare it "officially" as an answer!

Comment: ok:) both answers should make the magic, just from diff point of view. but i prefer the first one as it's much more simple solution. the second one is good when you want to make advanced visual effects ( like changing gaps between views while you're scrolling through the content )

Comment: Yeah i will go with the first one, short and really simple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's quite simple, create your constraint like this

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-(%.0f)-[testView]", y_coordinate]
                                        options:0
                                        metrics:nil
                                          views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings( testView )]];
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `stringWithFormat` like that. It's much better to use the metrics dictionary (which is there in the function). I will add an answer to show how.

Comment: why it isn't appropriate to use stringWithFormat method? is there some vulnerability in that code? btw: i know how to use metrics, just found out, that this is more readable solution also for my team members, but i'll be glad to hear the disadvantages

Comment: No vulnerability that I know of but it reduces readability for one. And the function provides a way to put variable values into the VFL string for you. Why would you go around that to do it a different way?

Comment: well this way you have just one string that makes exactly what you need, the other solution needs to create one more dictionary object (+nsnumber object)

Comment: Another thing (I just thought of) if you have a space that you want to use between several views you would have... `@"|-(%ld)-[view1]-(%ld)-[view2]-(%ld)-[view3]-(%ld)-|", (long)space, (long)space, (long)space, (long)space` If you have other widths that you want to put in there too then you need to make sure the list of values is all in the correct order. With metrics you insert it into a dict and just use the name. Doesn't matter about order and repeated values are used once.

Comment: your point is correct, you need to be aware of the order, like in every formatted function, which I or my colleagues doesn't find as disadvantage. this is probably more about the way how you handle constraints and all autolayout in your code. both ways are correct, just litlle bit different:)

Comment: Well, how I handle constraints is to do them relatively to each other rather than taking hard coded frames and plugging them into the constraints. I'd say this is more correct. Readability wise though. I may have... `@"|-(%ld)-[view1(%ld)]-(%ld)-[view2(%ld)]"` as a VFL constraint. This is fine except you have no idea what the spaces and widths mean without having to parse the string yourself. Are view1 and view2 the same width? Is the gap between view1 and view2 the same as the gap to the superview? To say that this is more readable is just incorrect.

Comment: actually there's "=" missing for width/height of each view -> [view1(=%ld)] ;) btw in my code I try to decomposite all that constraints mess in small testable methods, so I've never found myself struggling with long VFL definitions. that's probably why I've only one or two arguments in my stringWithFormat: method

Comment: No doubt. But I still can't see any justification for ignoring a part of the function you are using and favouring a method that makes everything less readable and harder to maintain. Each to their own I guess.

Comment: ok got your point, yeap, if you're using metrics, your constraints are more readable;)

Answer (score 2):

My Suggestion to you will be go through the auto layout tutorials online, and have a clear understanding of how the views layout themselves under "Autolayout".
One such example would be Ray Wenderlich's tutorial. Although this tutorial has not been dedicated for doing autolayout programmatically, but it does give a clear understanding of how the views are placed with the help of autolayout feature.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: Thanks for your response, i already read this article, but as you mention, it only covers the Part with Interfacer Builder and not programmatically...

Comment: Yeah i understand that you want to know how to code for autolayout programmatically, but that tutorial gives understanding of the layout of the views under "Autolayout". If you just want to learn about autolayout in code, then you can also have a look at another good tutorial : http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/
* If you have not already looked at it ;)

Answer (score 2):

@deathhorse answer may work but the metrics argument is designed for this...

```
NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"margin": @(y_coordinate)};

[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(margin)-[testView]"
                                        options:0
                                        metrics:metrics
                                          views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings( testView )]];
```

This makes it more readable too.

**EDIT**

Having looked at your question again I think you are going about this the wrong way anyway.

Yes, you can use Auto Layout **inside** the views to lay out the labels and image and stuff....

However, this view should be using a `UICollectionView` and not just laid out in a for loop like this. Even if you're only adding 4 and you don't want it to scroll it would be much more flexible as a `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Hmm yeah that makes Sense, if Apple provides such a function i should use it! Thanks for this! There´s only a little mistake with your Code above. I think it should be: NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"margin": @(y_coordinate)};

Comment: That´s a very good Point, especially it could be the case that i need way more than just 4 View´s... i will think about this :)

Comment: @Davis oh, if there is potential to use more than just the 4 views then there is no question. You should definitely be using `UICollectionView`. Doing it manually will be more difficult, slower (performance wise) and more memory hungry.